# Why I keep getting the error : org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "(" in my jdbc code?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jdbc

I am trying to write a method in jdbc in order to update some columns in my database (postgresql)
Here is what I have written so far:`

```java
    public void showRoomBookings(int clientID) {
            
            Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);
            Statement st;
            
            try {
                st = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
                
                ResultSet res = st.executeQuery("SELECT rb.\"hotelbookingID\",rb.\"roomID\",rb.\"bookedforpersonID\",rb.checkin,rb.checkout,rb.rate\r\n"
                        + "FROM roombooking rb ,hotelbooking hb\r\n"
                        + "where rb.\"bookedforpersonID\"=hb.\"bookedbyclientID\"\r\n"
                        + "AND hb.\"bookedbyclientID\"="+clientID+"\r\n"
                        + "order by rb.\"hotelbookingID\"");
                
                int j=1;
                while(res.next()) {
                    System.out.println(j+")roomID:"+res.getInt(2)
                    +"  bookedforpersonID:"+res.getInt(3)+"  checkin:"+res.getDate(4)+"  checkout:"+res.getDate(5)
                    +"  rate:"+res.getInt(6));
                    j++;
                }
                
                System.out.println("Enter the number of the room you want to update:");
                int answer = myObj.nextInt();
                
                ResultSet res1 = st.executeQuery("Select t2.\"hotelbookingID\",t2.\"roomID\",t2.\"bookedforpersonID\",t2.checkin,t2.checkout,t2.rate\r\n"
                        + "From \r\n"
                        + "(\r\n"
                        + "    Select \r\n"
                        + "      Row_Number() Over (Order By t1.\"hotelbookingID\") As RowNum\r\n"
                        + "    , *\r\n"
                        + "    From (\r\n"
                        + "SELECT rb.\"hotelbookingID\",rb.\"roomID\",rb.\"bookedforpersonID\",rb.checkin,rb.checkout,rb.rate\r\n"
                        + "FROM roombooking rb ,hotelbooking hb\r\n"
                        + "where rb.\"bookedforpersonID\"=hb.\"bookedbyclientID\"\r\n"
                        + "AND hb.\"bookedbyclientID\"=107\r\n"
                        + "order by rb.\"hotelbookingID\"\r\n"
                        + " )t1\r\n"
                        + ") t2\r\n"
                        + "Where RowNum = "+answer);
                
                
                System.out.println("You chose room: ("+answer+")");
                while(res1.next()) {
                    
                    System.out.println(res1.getInt(1)+"  roomID:"+res1.getInt(2)
                    +"  bookedforpersonID:"+res1.getInt(3)+"  checkin:"+res1.getDate(4)+"  checkout:"+res1.getDate(5)
                    +"  rate:"+res1.getInt(6));
                    res1.updateInt("rate", 40);
                    res1.updateRow();
                }
                
                
                res.close();
                res1.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
            
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            
            
            
        }
```

In the first ResultSet `res` I just project the roombookings bases on the **clientID** and then with ResultSet `res1` I choose one of them. My console looks like this:
[image]

The problem here is that when I try to update rate :

```
    res1.updateInt("rate", 40);
    res1.updateRow();
```

I get the following message:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "("
> Position: 8   at
> postgresql@42.2.20.jre7/org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2553)
> at
> postgresql@42.2.20.jre7/org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2285)
> at
> postgresql@42.2.20.jre7/org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:323)
> at
> postgresql@42.2.20.jre7/org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:481)
> at
> postgresql@42.2.20.jre7/org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:401)
> at
> postgresql@42.2.20.jre7/org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:164)
> at
> postgresql@42.2.20.jre7/org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PgPreparedStatement.java:130)
> at
> postgresql@42.2.20.jre7/org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.updateRow(PgResultSet.java:1445)
> at lol.DbApp.showRoomBookingss(DbApp.java:246)  at
> lol.DbApp.main(DbApp.java:290)

Here is my postgresql final result(the same as the last line from the console above):

[image]

**EDIT: SQL CODE:**

```sql
Select
  t2."hotelbookingID",
  t2."roomID",
  t2."bookedforpersonID",
  t2.checkin,
  t2.checkout,
  t2.rate
From(
    Select
      Row_Number() Over (
        Order By
          t1."hotelbookingID"
      ) As RowNum,
      *
    From
      (
        SELECT
          rb."hotelbookingID",
          rb."roomID",
          rb."bookedforpersonID",
          rb.checkin,
          rb.checkout,
          rb.rate
        FROM
          roombooking rb,
          hotelbooking hb
        WHERE
          rb."bookedforpersonID" = hb."bookedbyclientID"
          AND hb."bookedbyclientID" = 107
        order by
          rb."hotelbookingID"
      ) t1
  ) t2
Where
  RowNum = 3
group by
  t2."hotelbookingID",
  t2."roomID",
  t2."bookedforpersonID",
  t2.checkin,
  t2.checkout,
  t2.rate
```

Any help would be valuable.

Comment: Your code has two SQL statements, and you don't say which one is throwing the error. Please tell us.

Comment: Please include the actual SQL being ran in the question.

Comment: Is `Row_Number()` a **function** for the OVER clause? If so, does it take an argument?

Comment: @TheImpaler the error is in the 2nd sql statement when i am trying to perform update

Comment: @TheImpaler i edit the question with the sql code

Comment: The error suggests that the query generated by the PostgreSQL JDBC driver to back the update through the result set has a syntax error. However, I would be surprised if a complex query like that would even be updatable at all.

Comment: @DevilsHnd `ROW_NUMBER` doesn't take an argument.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel really?there is no solution for this? How can i update something like?

Comment: if i change my sql code to this :SELECT rb."hotelbookingID",rb."roomID",rb."bookedforpersonID",rb.checkin,rb.checkout,rb.rate
FROM client cl, person p, roombooking rb
WHERE cl."idClient" = '107'
AND p."idPerson" = cl."idClient"
AND rb."bookedforpersonID" = cl."idClient"
LIMIT 1 OFFSET (i-1)   ,where i is the position i want to choose i get a different error:No primary key found for table client.      Anyone can help?